# How do I use 2 include statements in a single MVC EF query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jsonresult

I am trying to write a query that includes 2 joins.

- 1 StoryTemplate can have multiple Stories
- 1 Story can have multiple StoryDrafts

I am starting the query on the StoryDrafts object because that is where it's linked to the UserId.

I don't have a reference from the StoryDrafts object directly to the StoryTemplates object.  How would I build this query properly?

```
    public JsonResult Index(int userId)
    {
        return Json(
            db.StoryDrafts
                .Include("Story")
                .Include("StoryTemplate")
                .Where(d => d.UserId == userId)
            ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to flatten your hierarchy if it works for you. Here is a sample, and you may want to customize it for your needs.

```
var result = from c in db.Customers
                    join o in db.Orders 
                    on c equals o.Customers
                    select new
                               {
                                   custid = c.CustomerID,
                                   cname = c.CompanyName,
                                   address = c.Address,
                                   orderid = o.OrderID,
                                   freight = o.Freight,                                   
                                   orderdate = o.OrderDate

                               };
```

If **flattering does not meet your requirements** then you need to **use query that returns** a [Nested Group.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545974.aspx) Finally, look at the following link for more references - [LINQ Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676) .